# how to get API response data with fetch function javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

i would like to get my API response datas, i am using the fetch function in javascript but i don't get the data field  in the response although my API returns a response when everything is ok. besides, when i call the API i have the `200` response status which prooves that the request works fine, here are the code i use to call the API and the screenshot of the response gotten from the API :

```
`function getAuthToken(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/authenticate",{
   method:"POST", headers:{'Accept':'Application/json; charset=utf-8',
   'Content-Type':'Application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  },

  body:JSON.stringify(credentials)
  }).then((response)=>{
 console.log("ramses");
 console.log(response.json().jwttoken);
//console.log(JSON.parse(response.statusText).jwttoken);

 if(response.status==200){
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/user/add",{
    method:"POST", 
    headers:{
     'Accept':'Application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Content-Type':'Application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
     'Authorization':'Bearer'+a
 },
 body:JSON.stringify(data),
 }).then(response => alert(JSON.stringify(response))).catch(error => alert("Erreur : " + error));
 }
 });
 }`
```

[image]

finally when i try to get the response with `response.data` in `console.log` it returns me the response `undefined`
if it could help, here is the response in console i got when i try with `response.json()`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetch function is a Promise which returns a response. After you waited to get this response call the .json() method which **also** returns a Promise. That's why you need to make 2. then().

```
fetch('yoururl')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Or you can call the fetch function with async-await inside an async function:

```
async function getData(){
let response = await fetch('yoururl');
let data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: i have tried with the 2 then solutions and it works very well.